# SonarQube: File is not a plugin. Please delete it and restart: sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to upgrade my SonarQube from SN4.0 to SN5.5. I would like to use the maven scanner(sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar) so I can make use of the PDF report. Unfortunately, I am hitting "File is not a plugin. Please delete it and restart: sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar".

I downloaded sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.2. Anything I missed on the SN5.5 setup?

Comment: I followed what it says, deleted the "sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar" at "extensions\plugins" directory and the sonarqube server starts. Now, I run the sonar maven scanner using the "sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.2.jar" plugin.  But then, I now encountered [ERROR] Failed to execute...: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar
-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources.
Project.getConfiguration()Lorg/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration;

Comment: I am using SN5.5, java 1.8.0_91, maven apache-maven-3.3.9 under windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SonarQube Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) is not a plugin, it's a scanner. That's why you don't need to deploy it in `extensions/plugins`, as per the `File is not a plugin. Please delete it and restart..` error.

Your other error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute...: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar -maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources. Project.getConfiguration()Lorg/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration

This is most likely due to a plugin which is not compatible with SonarQube 5.5. Review the plugins installed in our SonarQube server and cross-check their versions against the [Plugin Version Matrix](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix).

Comment: Thanks! The plugin version really gives me some trouble to use SN5.5. I am now encountering some issues on PDF report and waiting for the release of sonar-pdfreport-plugin-1.5.jar. For the meantime, I am forced to use SN4.5.7 instead.